# Newman & Postman: How to read input from a file using Newman

Tags: postman, newman

I have a csv file that contains the following:

```
value
one
two
three
four
five
```

I also have a variable in my Postman test script that simply takes each value in each of the 5 iterations and stores this value in {{variableValue}}.  So this variable gets updated with each of the 5 iterations.

Postman has a nice UI that I can use to import the input.csv file I'm using -- but how do I tell newman to import this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-d <source>` or `--iteration-data <source>` flag, from the command line.

https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/blob/develop/README.md#command-line-options